Не транслируется запрос к SQL Server проверяющий на содержание в базе данных любого значения из списка. C# EF
У меня есть такой код для поиска аналогов по кросс-номерам, он работает, если строка целиком совпадает, но только crossNumbers имеет такой вид
"021.181; 021181_SMP; 10502_SOYLU; 1202 1601; ", и мне нужно проверять не строку целиком, а каждую подстроку через точку с запятой.
var query = _context.Products
                .Where(p => p.CrossNumbers.Contains(crossNumbers) && p.Id != selectedProduct);

            var totalItems = await query.CountAsync();

Вот например какие варианты я пробовал еще и с одним итогом - could not be translated:
var crossNumbersArray = crossNumbers.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                         .Select(cn => cn.Trim())
                                         .ToArray();
    var query = _context.Products
                       .Where(p => crossNumbersArray.Any(cn => p.CrossNumbers.Contains(cn)) && p.Id != selectedProduct);

var crossNumberList = crossNumbers.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                      .Select(cn => cn.Trim())
                                      .ToList();

    var query = _context.Products
        .AsEnumerable() 
        .Where(p => crossNumberList.Any(cn => p.CrossNumbers.Contains(cn)) && p.Id != selectedProduct);

var crossNumberArray = crossNumbers.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        var query = _context.Products
            .Where(p => crossNumberArray.Any(cn => EF.Functions.Like(p.CrossNumbers, "%" + cn + "%")) && p.Id != selectedProduct);

var crossNumberArray = crossNumbers.Split(';', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    var query = _context.Products
        .Where(p => crossNumberArray.Any(cn => p.CrossNumbers.Contains(";" + cn + ";")) && p.Id != selectedProduct);



Строку надо парсить не в вызывающем коде, а в SQL-запросе. Функция STRING_SPLIT(). Ну а как это объяснить фреймворку - разбирайся сам.

Какой тип имеет p.CrossNumbers? На какой тип он смаплен в БД? И дополнительно напишите, какие значения содержатся в БД.

@Alexander Petrov CrossNumbers в модели - string?, CrossNumbers в бд nvarchar, значения везде одинаковые - в виде "021.181; 021181_SMP; 10502_SOYLU; 1202 1601;"

Соединить Enumerable и Queryable в одном запросе нельзя. Нужно или втащить запрос к базе в память (и сделать из него Enumerable), или передавать список в запрос.
Если база большая, а список поиска небольшой, то второе оптимальнее, естественно.
Есть и третий вариант - перебирать список и искать каждый элемент в базе.
List<Product> productsfound = new();
var crossNumbersArray = crossNumbers.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(cn => cn.Trim()).ToArray();
foreach (string cn in crossNumbersArray)
    productsfound.AddRange(_context.Products
        .Where(p => p.CrossNumbers.Contains(cn) && p.Id != selectedProduct));


В Entity Framework 8 можно использовать коллекции примитивных типов в свойствах.
Предлагаю слегка изменить свойство CrossNumbers, сделав его массивом (или любой другой подходящей коллекцией):
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string[]? CrossNumbers { get; set; }
}

В БД это будет храниться в виде массива JSON, в колонке с типом NVARCHAR(MAX).
Перед сохранением в БД строку следует расщепить, превратив в массив. Просто используем Split(';').
db.Products.Add(new Product { CrossNumbers = "A;B;C;D".Split(';') })
db.Products.Add(new Product { CrossNumbers = "E;F;G;H".Split(';') });
db.Products.Add(new Product { CrossNumbers = "B;C;F;G".Split(';') });

Теперь становится легко делать запросы. Просто делаем пересечение двух коллекций с помощью Intersect и проверяем, есть ли хоть одно совпадение: Any.
string crossNumbers = "A;B";
string[] crossNumbersArray = crossNumbers.Split(';');

var result = db.Products
    .Where(p => p.CrossNumbers.Intersect(crossNumbersArray).Any());

Можно и так записать условие:
    .Where(p => p.CrossNumbers.Any(s => crossNumbersArray.Contains(s)));

EF генерирует SQL-запрос с функцией OPENJSON.

Ваш вариант выглядит лучше моего, но мне придется многое переписывать и уверен столкнусь с большим количеством новых проблем, т.к у меня в приложении много велосипедов :)
Пока остановлюсь на варианте с перебором массива crossNumbersArray и отдельного поиска совпадений, а может и навсегда его оставлю. Правильным ответом выберу всё же второй, ибо он быстрее и намного проще подтолкнул к нужному решению
